# Lookup the first changed value in a column or return cell address

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with staff realtime status, which changes from idle to busy or vise-versa based on his status on the system, I'm trying to get the first changed cell in the status column within the last status.

for example below, it should be 'Avail' aka C12 since that's the first row of the current status. so it should ignore idle since there is another status after that, and busy..for the same reason. and idle. and go with the first row in Avail.

What I have so far.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/('Real-Time-Status'!B:B=B2),'Real-Time-Status''!D:D)
```

but it gets me the last value in status column. which is C5 in below sample, Instead of C12.

```
Name        ID     Status        Timestamp
John Doe    1111    Idle    24/03/2019 15:27:15
John Doe    1111    Idle    24/03/2019 15:27:49
John Doe    1111    Idle    24/03/2019 15:28:23
John Doe    1111    Idle    24/03/2019 15:28:59
John Doe    1111    Busy    24/03/2019 15:29:34
John Doe    1111    Busy    24/03/2019 15:30:11
John Doe    1111    Busy    24/03/2019 15:30:47
John Doe    1111    Busy    24/03/2019 15:31:25
John Doe    1111    Idle    24/03/2019 15:32:20
John Doe    1111    Idle    24/03/2019 15:33:00
John Doe    1111    Idle    24/03/2019 15:34:05
John Doe    1111    Avail   24/03/2019 15:35:25
John Doe    1111    Avail   24/03/2019 15:36:25
John Doe    1111    Avail   24/03/2019 15:37:25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to return column D value:

[image]

The formula I used translates to:

```
{=INDEX(D1:D15,MAX(--((C1:C15<>LOOKUP(2,1/(C:C<>""),C:C))*ROW(C1:C15)))+1)}
```

Notice it's an array formula and should be entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

In case your data actually includes more persons, it may look like this:

[image]

The formula used in that example translates to:

```
{=INDEX(D1:D15,MAX(--(C1:C15<>INDEX(C1:C15,MAX(--(A1:A15=F2)*(ROW(A1:A15)))))*(A1:A15=F2)*ROW(C1:C15))+1)}
```

It is again an array formula. And you might want to consider to use absolute cell references for the range.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't suit this to work with what I needed. so bear with me please :), I cannot set the D column references as fixed range since each staff can have multiple rows depending on the time he spent, also.  I tried adding some extra rows showing idle status after the busy rows, the formula is still showing the cell reference adjacent to the busy status cell.. we need it to get cell reference or the timestamp of the first row of the last status.. which is idle in that case. and if that idle changed again to X, it should give the X. hope you got me :)

Comment: I went with your sample data. Please update your question with this relevent information

Comment: @Se7sNator, see edited answer and let me know if that suits the problem.

Comment: Everything went better than expected, and it's working with multi staff also. :) Thank you so much for your assitance and please excuse my first dull question attempt .